# How would I add and implement google cloud vision api into a flutter project?

Tags: flutter, project, google-cloud-vision

I have tried to look it up, and it seems like no one else had done it, and when I try, I have no idea what to do. Are there any examples of someone using this api in a flutter project? I want to extract colors and styles of clothing from the api.

I tried using it like any other api that you should be using in flutter, but it doesn't work, and I don't know how to extract the tags that it generates.